# Generate pixel based image in R from character array

Tags: r, bitmap, raster

I have a very long character array. I want to generate pixel based image (raster image) by encoding each character to certain color in image. For example, 'A' as red pixel, 'B' as purple, ... and 'Z' by some other color.  I am using R for it.

Please help me how can i generate such pixel based image. I search and found raster and pixmap packages in R but i am new to R and not sure how to use them for my case. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can you show some example data? How about assigning numeric values to the characters?

Comment: @ din. the example array is txt <- "ABACDAAFFEDDADFAFAEDDGJHGHJKL ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible solution :

```
library(png)
library(tiff)
library(abind)

# function which plots the image
createImage <- function(txt,charToColorMap,destinationFile,format=c('png','tiff'),debugPlot=FALSE){

  # helper function which finds all the divisors of a number
  divisors <- function(x){
    y <- seq_len(x)
    y[ x%%y == 0 ]
  }

  # split the string in charaters
  chars <- strsplit(txt,'')[[1]]

  # find the most "squared" rectangle that contains all the characters without padding
  d <- divisors(length(chars)) 
  y <- d[length(d) %/% 2]
  x <- length(chars) / y

  # create an array with 4 matrices (or planes) one for each RGBA channel
  RGBAmx <- col2rgb(charToColorMap,alpha=TRUE) / 255
  colorIndexes <- match(chars,names(charToColorMap))

  colorIndexesR <- matrix(RGBAmx['red',colorIndexes],nrow=y,ncol=x,byrow = TRUE)
  colorIndexesG <- matrix(RGBAmx['green',colorIndexes],nrow=y,ncol=x,byrow = TRUE)
  colorIndexesB <- matrix(RGBAmx['blue',colorIndexes],nrow=y,ncol=x,byrow = TRUE)
  colorIndexesA <- matrix(RGBAmx['alpha',colorIndexes],nrow=y,ncol=x,byrow = TRUE)

  planes <- abind(colorIndexesR,colorIndexesG,colorIndexesB,colorIndexesA,along=3)

  # write the PNG image
  if(format[1] == 'png'){
    writePNG(planes,destinationFile)
  }else if(format[1] == 'tiff'){
    writeTIFF(planes,destinationFile)
  }else{
    stop('usupported format')
  }

  # for debug purpose only we plot the image...
  if(debugPlot){
    mx <- matrix(colorIndexes,nrow=y,ncol=x,byrow = TRUE)
    image(z=t(mx[nrow(mx):1,]),col=charToColorMap)
  }

  invisible()
}
```

Usage :

```
# arbitrary and incomplete LETTER -> COLOR map 
charToColorMap <- c(A='red',B='blue',C='green',D='black',E='yellow',F='orange')

txt <- "ABACDAAFFEDDADFAFAED"

createImage(txt,charToColorMap,destinationFile = "test.png",debugPlot=TRUE)
```

Resulting PNG image (800% zoom to see the pixels) :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution @digEmAll. Instead of png how can we used tiff because for large character arrays png will compress the image. I need bitmap image without compression. Thanks again.

Comment: @user7639992 Hmm PNG uses a lossless compression. Or do you mean 8 bit of color information is not enough?

Comment: @lukeA In my understanding writePNG compresses the image in png format. Even if its a lossless compression how it is different from Tiff?

Comment: @user7639992 Yes it compresses the image in png. But it's no lossy compression like jpg. Compression preserves all information - except for color in case of 8-bit PNG, if you have more than 256 colors. But that does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: @lukeA ok got it. Nice explanation. One last question that tiff just not do any compression, right? if tiff is using 8 bits than it is same as png? Thanks

Comment: @user7639992: if you need a TIFF file you can use writeTIFF of package tiff; see my edited answer ;)

Comment: @user7639992: well, that's a huge array and with such a size, I don't think this is the right approach to use...maybe you can writing something ad-hoc in C++ (maybe using Rcpp) to map a character with a color...

Comment: @digEmAll How can i update the above code for handling case where i have a character presents 2 or three times consecutively and i want to give it a different color. For example  txt <- "ABBACDAAFFFEDDADFAFAED", i want to give A- red, B-green, BB- Pink, BBB-yellow, C-brown, etc. I still want to give 1 pixel to each char but for consecutive 2 or 3 appearances give them different colors. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: @user7639992: you need to provide more information...I suggest you to open a new question

Comment: I open a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47071014/pixel-image-in-r-from-character-array    Thanks